# Magento Upgrade Issue from 1.4.2 to 1.6

Tags: magento

Error in file:

```
/usr/local/sites/client/magento_site/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.4.0.0.7-1.4.0.0.8.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'customer_form_attribute' already exists
```

I tried upgrading this using [this tutorial](http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-from-1-4-version-to-magento-1-5-magento-1-6/) from turnkeye to go from 1.4.1 -> 1.4.2 and then to 1.6 but after all the mage upgrading was complete, when I hit the website to upgrade the database I get errors about database tables that already exist and it appears to be running a database upgrade script for a version of magento before 1.4.2. I know this error is extremely common and I have seen many blogs posts about it and read all that I have found -- I see no resolution besides starting a fresh install.

I've heard people say this can happen if a previous upgrade didn't complete successfully but I don't think that is the case here -- I think it was a fresh install at 1.4.1 (at least I don't believe I ever upgraded it). Anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Note 1: I also tried the upgrade by overwriting the 1.4.1 files via SSH with successive version of magento -- always the same database errors though. If I remove the mysql-upgrade script that is failing, then another one fails in its place with a simliar 'table already exists' error.

Note 2: I also made sure I cleared `/var/cache` and `/var/session` and even tried reindexing. No success.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is just complaining about a table already existing. Either install a fresh version of you database from before you tried to upgrade then clear cache and sessions and try again

Or

Just open the file referenced and temporarly comment out the part that is installing the table again. That should allow you to by pass the error.
Then you can download the magento Database Repair Tool to ensure that your tables are correct.